# how to use progress bar show array count in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, progress

I want the progress bar to read whether the completed in my array has completed value ,If there is a strikethrough when done, the progress bar will also change

Sorry I may not be very clear but i want like the following

[image]

this is my code

```
   class ListTableViewController: UITableViewController {     

   @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!

   var progress: Float {
       if item.lists.count > 0 {
           return Float(item.lists.filter({$0.completed}).count) / Float(item.lists.count)
       } else {
           return 0
       }
   }

   var item: ItemCard! {
       didSet {
           if let progressView = progressView {
           // it's not work
           progressView.setProgress(progress, animated: true)
           }
       }
}
```

This is my data. There are lists = List in the ItemCard. I want to get completed in the list as the display of the progress bar.

```
class ItemCard: NSObject, Codable {

  var title: String
  var isFinish: Bool
  var lists = [List]()


  init(title: String, isFinish: Bool) {
      self.title = title
      self.isFinish = false
      super.init()
  }
  }

class List: NSObject, Codable {

  var name: String
  var completed:Bool

  init(name:String, completed:Bool) {
      self.name = name
      self.completed = completed
  } 
 }
```

I use didSet for item variables but it is not valid

Comment: Unrelated by there is probably no reason for your `ItemCard` and `List` classes to be classes (use `struct`) nor extend `NSObject`.

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: The progress bar does not show the completion value

Comment: What does it show? How is it setup? What are its min and max values?

Comment: Please post the code where the item is being set and where the lists in the item is being updated

Comment: Is the property `item` set every time you complete an item?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var progresview: UIProgressView!
let sampleArray = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50,60,70,80]
let arrayCount = sampleArray.count
if sampleArray.count > 0 {
   for i in 1...sampleArray.count {
                let progress = (Float((Int(i)))/Float(arrayCount))
                self.progressview.setProgress(Float(progress),animated:true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you have a new `ItemCard`, count the number of completed lists, divide by the number of your lists and update the progress.
Should look something like this.

```
var item: ItemCard! {
    didSet {
        let completedListsCount = self.item.lists.map { $0.completed }
                                                 .filter { $0 }
                                                 .count
        let progress = Double(completedLists.count / self.item.lists.count)
        progressView.setProgress(progress, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: completedLists.count is let completedListsCount ?

Comment: Int + Int = Int

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided the code that marks the list as complete.

But, as per your implementation you have to re-assign self.item with same value after marking the list as complete. For example, if you mark your list as complete in on tap over a row then `didSelectRowAt` will look like

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let item = self.item
    let list = item!.lists[indexPath.row]
    list.completed = true

    self.item = item

    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```

Or call below code just after marking the list as completed

`progressView.setProgress(progress, animated: true)`